# Make a 3 Bit Counter count out of order

Tags: logic, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I'm currently messing around with flip flops and I've made a 3-Bit counter with (3) D Flip Flops. I was wondering if there was a way to get it to count of out order. So as of right now, a typical counter counts from 0-7, or binary: 000 -> 111 before resetting back to 0. However, what logic would need to be input to make it count for example: 0, 1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 7, 2 --> back to 0 again? I've been screwing around, obviously I'll need some logic gates somewhere. But not entirely sure how/where to alter it with this design[image: 3 Bit Counter with D FlipFlops]

Comment: Simplest way would be to define a mapping between your current output lines xyz (000,001,010,011,,..) to your preferred output lines x'y'z' (000,001,110,011,...), then for each preferred output line prepare a truth table with your inputs and output and solve it with a Karnaugh map or use http://www.32x8.com/var3.html

Comment: @hayesti I get the kmap and truth table portion of this. But how do I use the counter to jump from 1 to 6 (skipping 2-5) and then coming right back down on the next clock tick to 3? That's where I'm getting confused.

Comment: I'm just explaining the suggestion by @hayesti...You don't need to jump, you just continue as usual, your output of the current counter stays the same (000,001,010,011...). You then feed this to an extra logic circuit you prepared to convert this to your preferred format (000,001,110,011,...). You'll need a karnaugh map taking (000,001,010,011...) as inputs and producing (000,001,010,011...) as outputs. So on the 3rd clock, your original counter will produce 010 which then fed to the second circuit and it will produce 110.

Comment: Now if you box the whole thing, you have one input (clock) and three outputs which produce your arbitrary sequence.

Comment: @IsuruH Okay I get/see how that works. So if I wanted to try doing every other odd/even and back (so lets do evens): 0, 4, 2, 6

I have a truth table with 1's for 000, 010, 100, 110 and my K-Map produces: C'. 

I can get that far no problem, I'm just lacking knowledge on how to translate that into my gates. Especially now that I've eliminated 4 numbers/clock ticks. Like what if I only wanted to count: 1, 7, 2. I now have 8 clicks but 3 numbers?

Comment: Oh I would need 3 Kmap outputs right? For my 3 outputs from the flip flops. Hm, yeah I'm so lost! :) I'll just keep messing with it, then just move on to my next flip flop

Comment: exactly.. I was typing one in csv format to post here. Now that you've go it right, I guess you wont need it anymore. I've posted it below anyway. That one does every other even first and afterwards same with odds

Comment: clock,intermediate output,,,,final output1,final output2,final output3
,0,0,0,,0,0,0
,0,0,1,,1,0,0
,0,1,0,,0,1,0
,0,1,1,,1,1,0
,1,0,0,,0,0,1
,1,0,1,,1,0,1
,1,1,0,,0,1,1
,1,1,1,,1,1,1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136443/discussion-between-john-barr-and-isuru-h).